# Symfony Encore multiple asset manifests

Tags: symfony, webpack, manifest, versioning

I have a question regarding Encore in Symfony 3.4 and asset versioning.

In my `webpack.config.js`I have two configurations.
First is for JS files, the other one for compiling .less.

Each configuration is reset by Encore.reset()

Output bundles are generating manifest with versioning via `.enableVersioning`, so I have two `manifest.json` in

```
web/js/manifest.json
web/stylesheets/manifest.json
```

According to docs, to have my assets loaded via manifest I need to declare it in `config.yml`

```
   assets:
        base_path: "%myapp.http.site_assets_suffix%" 
        stylesheets:
            json_manifest_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/web/assets/stylesheets/manifest.json"
```

If I want to link to `style.css` generated by webpack, I use

```
asset("stylesheets/style.css")
```

But in my application I have two manifests and I think this can't be changed due to two Encore configurations.

I've tried adding something in likes of

```
packages:
     stylesheets:
                json_manifest_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/web/assets/stylesheets/manifest.json"
     js:
                json_manifest_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/web/assets/js/manifest.json"
```

because I saw that somewhere, but unfortunately this won't work at all.

I've thought about combining two manifests into one in last webpack entry point, but this can be time consuming.

Is there any other solution than combining manfiests or combining js + less compilation into one big Encore task?

Comment: Could you share your webpack.config.js ?

Comment: @svantetic Did you solve this? If you did, please share your solution to contribute back to community.

Comment: @YahyaE added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution

```
assets:
    base_path: 'path%'
    packages:
        noversion:
            version: false
            version_format: "%%1$s"
            base_path: "path%"
        stylesheets:
            json_manifest_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/web/assets/stylesheets/manifest.json"
        js:
            json_manifest_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/web/assets/js/manifest.json"
        admin:
            json_manifest_path: "%kernel.project_dir%/web/assets/js/admin/manifest.json"
```

And then in `.twig` files, you need to call it as

```
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/DIRNAME/WEBPACK_ENTRY_NAME_HERE', ASSET_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE) }}"></script>
```

In my case

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/backend.js', 'js') }}"></script>
```

Where `WEBPACK_ENTRY_NAME` is the name of the Webpack/Encore bundle from `webpack.config.js`, in my case

```
.setOutputPath('./web/assets/js')
    .setPublicPath('/assets/js')
    .addEntry('backend',
```

Sorry for delayed answer, but I forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack Encore use [webpack-manifest-plugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) to generate `manifest.json` file.

According to the doc, you can specify an `options.seed` when you setup your config.

> A cache of key/value pairs to used to seed the manifest. This may include a set of custom key/value pairs to include in your manifest, or may be used to combine manifests across compilations in multi-compiler mode. To combine manifests, pass a shared seed object to each compiler's ManifestPlugin instance.

```
 Encore.configureManifestPlugin(options => {
            let seed;

            try {
                // require your existing manifest content if exists
                seed = require(path.join(outputPath, 'manifest.json'));
            }

            catch (e) {
                // fallback if manifest.json is missing
                seed = {};
            }

            // inject your latest config as seed.
            // The plugin will update it and rewrite manifest.json with correct values (overwrite existing keys, append news)
            options.seed = seed;

           // Also i add a trick to avoid "License.txt" entries
            options.generate = function(seed, files, entrypoints) {
                // trick to avoid generate useless versionned entries like License
                const filesWithoutLicense = files.filter(file => {
                    return file.path.match(/.*LICENSE.*/) === null;
                });

                const newManifestContent = filesWithoutLicense.reduce(
                    (newManifestContent, file) => {
                        newManifestContent[file.name] = file.path;
                        return newManifestContent;
                    },

                    seed
                );


                return newManifestContent;
            }
```